# How could I get the text and href value in HTML and then set them to values & labels in autocompelte of JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Currently I get this

JS

```
$(function() {
$("#nav-list123").fadeOut();
$('input').autocomplete({
    source: function(req, response) {
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" );
        var sources = $('.search').select ('li'); 
        response($.grep(sources.text(), function(item){return matcher.test(item.label); }) );
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#state_id').val(ui.item.label);
        $('#abbrev').val(ui.item.value);
    }
});});
```

within this html

```
<div><form class="form-search"><input id="autocomplete" type="text"/></form>
<div id="nav-list123">                   
    <ul class="search">
    <li><a href="/order_gen/address/1/">  Kitchen Visions</a></li>
    <li><a href="/order_gen/address/4/">  Full Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="/order_gen/address/23/">  Job B</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to get the elements attributes in the `<li>`, i tried using `.text()` or `.html()` to get text, but I do not know how to convert these attributes to label and value in autocomplete function from JQuery UI to get the match elements.

Could anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the value & href of ul li into an javascript array on page load
& pass this array in autocomplete source

var arr = new Array();
$('ul > li').each(function(){
      var temp_obj = {
                label:$(this).children('a').attr('href'),
                value:$(this).children('a').text().trim()
      }
      arr.push(temp_obj);
});

//Pass this array in autocomplete source
$('input').autocomplete({
 focus: function( event, ui ) {
       $( "#your_id" ).val( ui.item.value );
       return false;
},
source: arr
});